# Método em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

O que faltou definir neste método? ...

```js
function fiz(){
    alert('Eu fiz, o que não fiz!');
}
eu.pensamento = fiz;
eu.pensamento();
```

Comment: `eu` por exemplo.

Comment: nem, percebi.. desculpa parceiro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa definir `eu` como um objeto. Assim você pode construir o método `eu.pensamento()` como uma função de `fiz()`:

```js
function fiz(){
   alert('Eu fiz, o que não fiz!');
}

var eu = new Object();
eu.pensamento = fiz;
eu.pensamento();

console.log(eu.pensamento);
```

Comment: valeu! tirou minha dúvida

Answer (score 0):

Se eu crio uma variável `eu`, `eu.pensamento` não é uma função? como eu defino este método com a função fiz, em `eu.pensamento()`? se tiver um código como exemplo, ajudaria bastante ..

```js
eu = 'Eu...'
function fiz(){
    alert('Eu fiz, o que não fiz!');
}
eu.pensamento = fiz;
eu.pensamento();
```

Comment: Você definiu a variável global "eu" como uma string. A variável `eu` contém métodos de string, e desse jeito que você fez `eu.pensamento` é errado. O jeito certo era você ter atribuído a variável "eu" como um objeto literal, exemplo: `var eu = {} `. Substitua a primeira linha pelo exemplo.